# Accessing singleton methods in PHP

Tags: php, oop, static, singleton, methods

I'm just starting my journey into OOP - and I'm currently trying to roll my own MVC - purely for learning purposes. I'm working through a tutorial in the Apress PHP-Objects Patterns Practice book. I've created a registry singleton object using the private __construct/__clone technique:

```
class Registry
{
  private static $instance;
  private $values = array();


  private function __construct(){}
  private function __clone(){}

  public static function getInstance(){
       if( !isset( self::$instance ) ){
         self::$instance = new Registry();
         }
       return self::$instance;
       }

  public function get( $key ) {
      if ( isset( $this->values[$key] ) ) {
          return $this->values[$key];
          }
      return null;
      }

  public function set( $key, $val ) {
      $this->values[$key] = $val;
      }
  }
```

I get an instance of this object directly i.e:

```
Registry::getInstance();
```

However, (following the syntax in the tutorial) - if I try and access the public methods using the '->' method - e.g:

```
Registry->setVal('page',$page);
```

I get a parse error. I can only access the methods using the scope resolution operator - i.e '::'.

I'm assuming this is because the object wrapper has not been *instantiated* - but I just want to verify/discuss this issue with y'all...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Registry::getInstance()` returns a (in fact the only) instance of the class `Registry`. It has the same return value as `new Registry()`, just that there will can only one instance in your whole application. These are your possibilities to access the methods:

```
// #1
$registry = Registry::getInstance();
$registry->set($key, $value);

// #2
Registry::getInstance()->set($key, $value);
```

Another trick:

Map `get()` and `set()` to their magic methods.

```
public function __set($key, $value)
{
    return $this->set($key, $value);
}

public function __get($key)
{
    return $this->get($key);
}
```

So you can use either `Registry::getInstance()->set($key, $value);` or `Registry::getInstance()->$key = $value;`

Comment: That answers my question....
While I'm here - if an earlier process initialises the Registry class using Registry::getInstance - can subsequent unrelated classes reference the Registry::set() methods without jumping through the same hoop - or do I have to initialise that object for every object that wants to access it's methods?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call setVal() on an instance, not the class itself, so you could do this:

```
Registry::getInstance()->set('page', $page);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to put the object creation in the class, rather than have to reference it on each usage:

```
public static function get( $key ) {
    $instance = self::getInstance();
    if ( isset( $instance->values[$key] ) ) {
        return $instance->values[$key];
    }
    return null;
}
```

And call it with just `Registry::set('page', $page);`

That way you do a get a bit nicer code where it's used, even though the singleton should still be considered a warning sign (there's already a ton of good thread on why on stackoverflow if you search).